# Bridging Faces Gives Error Message

Tags: modeling, faces

I have a problem with bridging the faces selected in the first picture.

[image]

When I click *Bridge Faces* this error message pops up:
Select at least two edge loops

[image]

What might cause the problem?

Comment: Hello :). Make sure both meshes are joined into one object (Ctrl+J). Otherwise it won't work :).

Comment: @JachymMichal ahaha omg thank you so much, didn't know it works that way. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error message twice:

[image]

Which means you are currently operating on two separate meshes.  Each mesh has a face selected so neither is able to complete the operation.

If you join the objects by selecting them in *Object Mode* and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> you will be able to run the operation normally.

Comment: Thank you, it's working solution for this problem.